# Using TinyMCE within a Semantic UI modal

Tags: modal-dialog, tinymce, semantic-ui

I'm having troubles getting TinyMCE to work within a Semantic UI modal. Everything looks fine and without errors but it's not possible to put the cursor within the TinyMCE editor.

I found these solutions but none seems to work for Semantic UI:
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_boostrap_dialog
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_jQuery_UI_dialog

I'm using Aurelia and TypeScript.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: what the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: @Raúl, the modal is opened and the TinyMCE editor i shown, but it is not possible to focus the input area.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little late to the party, but for anyone looking I found that the TinyMCE editor appeared to work fine if I set the `detachable: false` option on the Semantic UI modal. Here's a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mpauly/nkt2mmuu/